# Format the keys of an array with quote

Tags: php, sql, arrays

i have an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => bag [1] => resource [2] => 120 [3] => little dog [4] => 700.25 ...
```

Is it possible a function that return every key with a quote if a string, without quote if is a number, like

```
'bag','resource',120,'little dog',700.25 ...
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: you want to do this in sql? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$input  = array('bag', 'resource', 120, 'little dog');
$output = trim(json_encode($input), '[]');
```

or basing on `@Rajat Garg` solution:

```
$input  = array('bag', 'resource', 120, 'little dog');
$data   = array();
foreach ( $input as $value ) {
  $data[] = is_numeric($value) ? $value : "'$value'";
}
$output = implode($data, ',');
```

Comment: For better control i've prefer to use the second option. Thank you!

Comment: You can also improve first option with `array_values`: `trim(json_encode(array_values($input)), '[]')`

Comment: I'm new here and, for now, is it impossible to Vote Up because needs to have a minimum of 15 reputation (at the moment i've only 6 reputations)

Answer (score 0):

Use is_numeric to identify if its a number, and concatenate quotes otherwise:

```
foreach($array as $value){
    if(is_numeric($value)){
         echo $value;
      } else{
           echo "'".$value."'";
      }
 }
```